# An attempt was made to call the method spring kafka

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am having a bit of trouble integrating spring-kafka with spring-boot. I am using spring boot v2.1 with spring-kafka v2.2 (which should be compatible according to the matrix).
I have seen multiple similar questions but none of them fixes my problem.

The error from the logs:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call the method org.springframework.kafka.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.getContainerProperties()Lorg/springframework/kafka/listener/config/ContainerProperties; but it does not exist. Its class, org.springframework.kafka.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/Ali/.m2/repository/org/springframework/kafka/spring-kafka/2.2.0.RELEASE/spring-kafka-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/kafka/listener/AbstractMessageListenerContainer.class

It was loaded from the following location:

    file:/C:/Users/Ali/.m2/repository/org/springframework/kafka/spring-kafka/2.2.0.RELEASE/spring-kafka-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.kafka.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer

2022-06-28 13:21:16,716 INFO  [,,,] [main] ThreadPoolTaskExecutor[shutdown]: Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
```

My dependency in the pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

My code:

```
@Component
public class MyListenerComponent {

  @KafkaListener(topics="myTopic")
  public void Listen(MyModelClass obj) {
    //do stuff (nothing complicated, basic java stuff)
  }
}
```

My Application:

```
@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableKafka
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

I can't seem to find examples/samples dating back to v2.2.

I am not using any other listeners or containers like JMS or MQ, so there should be no conflicts (seen a similar question where RabbitMQ was causing conflicts).

The error only seems to happen when I use the KafkaListener annotation, Is there a fix or alternative way to deal with listeners?

Comment: I’d suggest you to update to the latest Spring Boot as much as possible and try to rely on the spring-kafka it manages for us.

Comment: I wish I could,  but this is one of those cases where upgrading is not an option due to a myriad of reasons which I have no control over.

Comment: Well, don’t try to change Spring Kafka version then ! Still rely on whatever Spring Boot brings for us. The Kafka client should be compatible with a bunch of Kafka broker versions

Comment: I am not changing the spring-kafka version, it auto selects the one that is supposedly compatible with my spring boot version. However, I am not sure why it breaks whenever I use this specific annotation. (other annotations work like a charm)

Comment: Because exactly this annotation creates a listener container. It is not clear what is auto-selected. If everything is Spring Boot, then why you mention exactly this Spring Kafka version? Any chances to share with us a simple project to reproduce? May we understand who makes a call to that method?

Comment: In any case, those versions are no longer supported; see my answer for the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

In any case; those versions are no longer supported; even commercially https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#support and https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka#support let alone OSS.

The root cause is definitely a mis-matched version because that class (`ContainerProperties`) was moved from `config` to `listener` in 2.2.

> An attempt was made to call the method org.springframework.kafka.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.getContainerProperties()Lorg/springframework/kafka/listener/config/ContainerProperties; but it does not exist. Its class, org.springframework.kafka.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer, is available from the following locations:

Whatever is calling `getContainerProperties()` was compiled against an earlier version.